# Why air rushes out of bottle if we pore hot water in it and close cap and squeeze when air moves out?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

Suppose I fill a bottle with hot water. It inflates! Does the pressure inside bottle become the same as the pressure outside? I think it does because as the air in bottle expands due to hot water, the volume of bottle also expands, creating an equal pressure inside and outside. Is my assumption correct?

**The plastic bottle is like the kind used for soft drinks.**

**Then, if pressure is equal inside and outside, why does air move out when we open the cap?**

---

Please check my reasoning and tell me whether it is correct or not:

When we squeeze plastic bottle (flexible), some air escapes and instantly close the cap; the bottle remains squeezed in shape.

The flexible bottle tries to return to its original shape. However, it contains less air than earlier, creating a low pressure, thus making atmospheric pressure to squeeze bottle up to that extent until inside and outside pressure is equal with that amount of air.

Now, suppose I fill the bottle with some hot water and close the cap. The air in bottle expands in that limited volume, creating a high pressure and therefore pushes the wall of bottle outside until the pressure inside and outside is balanced. The bottle tries to return to its original shape but if it does, it will contract that hot air creating high pressure so it does squeeze but expand to maintain equilibrium.

If we open the cap and the bottle returns to its original shape, creating high pressure. But the cap is now open and air has a way to leave. Therefore, excess air leaves and a normal condition is established.

**Please tell me whether my reasoning is correct.**

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of factors involves here, namely pressure and the elasticity of the material of the bottle. If you heat a closed bottle containing some air and some water, the pressure inside the bottle will increase, so the bottle will expand.

As the bottle expands, two things happen- one is that the pressure generated by the contents will be reduced, as it now has more volume. The other is that the material of the bottle is stretched.

The bottle will continue to expand until a point of equilibrium is reached at which the excess pressure of the contents is counteracted by the elastic forces of the bottle trying to return to its original shape.

If you open the lid, some of the air will come out to equalise the pressure with the surrounding atmosphere and to allow the elastic forces in the bottle to relax.

Depending on how accurately you want to model the effects, you might also want to consider the extent to which the thermal expansion of the bottle plays a part. You can probably ignore it, since the thermal expansion of the sort of materials from which bottles are made are low compared with the expansion of the air and water vapour in the bottle.

Comment: But if pressure us already equalize by bottle that why air leaves as we open cap

Comment: Because the bottle has been stretched by the expanding air, like stretching an elastic band. The bottle is squeezing the expanded air to prevent it from expanding any further. When you open the cap you create a gap where the expanded air can leave the bottle- so the stretched bottle squeezes the air out.

Comment: So u mean air in bottle is in HP because it has to equalize bottle elasticity + atmph. Pressure??

Comment: All together the system is equal??

Comment: You are confusing cause and effect. The air is high pressure because it is heated. The higher pressure of the air inside the bottle causes the bottle to expand until the elastic forces in the bottle grow to counteract the excess pressure completely.

Comment: Yah that i m saying....see if pressure increase , now bottle has high pressure than out so equalize it....bottle expands upto the point when pressure equalize by bottle wall and outer atmosphere....that is bottle's expanded wall also exerting some pressure along with atmosphere in the inner of bottle ...to handle the HP inside??

Comment: I also want to ask,    As bottle expands won't the pressure inside start decreasing and pressure from outside start in reading as wall expanding ?? But still inner pressure is comparatively higher than atmosphere pressure in order to counteract the wall pressure along with atmosphere. Pressure?? No???yes?..

Comment: Yes, the air pressure inside the bottle with be higher than the air pressure outside. The excess pressure is what stretches the bottle.

Comment: Thank u and pls also answer The other que I asked in comment...1hr ago and yah one writing mistake       it is NOT 'in reading' but 'increasing' in that question i ask u to answer